# Retaining Indentation of the list after adding to PdfCell

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I am adding list inside pdfcell.But the identation of this list is not coming properly.
its coming like this:

```
• One 
• Two
• Three
```

But the same list if add directly to the document,the identation is coming properly.Like below:

```
• One 
   • Two
• Three
```

here is the code :

```
list = new List(false, 14.4F);
list.ListSymbol = new Chunk("\u2022", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10,iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
ListItem listItem;
listItem = new ListItem(lstrBullets.Trim(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
list.IndentationLeft = lftBulletIndent;    
listItem.SetLeading(10.0F, 1.0F);
listItem.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
list.Add(listItem);
PdfCell cell = new PdfCell();
cell.AddElement(list);
pobjTable.AddCell(cell);
```

where **lftBulletIndent** gives the indentation values for list.Please help what i am missing here.How can i retain the indentaion inside a cell?

Comment: I can't reproduce your document-based version. I don't think changing `list.IndentationLeft` a bunch of times should do anything. That property shouldn't be read by iText until the `Process` method is called when you add it to something. Can you post some code that shows that working? Also, unless it is a typo, since you said `PdfCell` does that mean you are using the very old, deprecated and unsupported 4.1.6 version?

Comment: @ChrisHaas : i am using older version of the iTextsharp(3.1.8.0).

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to a newer version? The current version is 5.4.3 and it might solve your problems. 3.1.8.0 is six or seven years old and is _way_ past the support window.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: i cant upgrade to newer version.Instead i have found workaround its giving the required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how I solved this. I know this is not a proper one.But it worked for me.
I am adding a table with variable width in the first cell of the parent table i.e here pobjTable

```
PdfPTable DummyTable = new PdfPTable(2);
//Here the floatSpace value changes according to the lftBulletIndent values
float[] headerwidths = { 2f + floatSpace, 98f - floatSpace};
DummyTable.SetWidths(headerwidths);

Pcell = new PdfPCell();
Pcell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
DummyTable.AddCell(Pcell);


Pcell = new PdfPCell();
Pcell.AddElement(list);
Pcell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
DummyTable.AddCell(Pcell);

pobjTable.AddCell(DummyTable);//Inserting a new table here
pobjTable.AddCell("");
```